# Did Deceptia really deceive me or is there a chance of respawn?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I was running around in Talador, doing a bonus quest in the upper north-west where you have to kill shredders and collect wood.

In the middle of this, I found a quest hub with a couple of NPC. When I was approaching it to get more quests that I can do, it exploded and all that was left was a pair of [smoking boots](http://www.wowhead.com/item=108743).

[image: screenshot of incident]

Considering the name, I guess it will not respawn, however, my OCD requires resolution.
Will this camp respawn eventually? Will I be able to take the quest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of the current patch: **No the camp will not respawn**. It's simply a prank by Blizzard to *deceive* you. It's kinda unclear whether Deceptia has survived or not but for the moment she doesn't appear anywhere else in the game.

I guess it's just Blizzards way of making you hate the Iron horde even more. Now they even kill your quest NPCs!